# C# mvc4 Best way to save server cache for long time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, server

I use C# mvc4 and EF5.0
In my DB I have table named "Settings" that contains the app settings for all the users.
The settings are change only once a month, but I use the settings for almost every action in my controller.
At the moment I created contractor to my controller that check if "HttpContext.Current.Application["Settings"]" is null, and if is null i load it from the DB.

My question is what is the best way to get this data without getting it from the DB every time?
I don't care to recycle the IIS once a month...

Thanks

Comment: If the data is being populated only upon `Application_Start()`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it just settings, you can simply save it in the memory

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
public DateTime LastUpdated {get;set;}
public Settings  GetSettings()
    {
        if (settings  == null || LastUpdated.AddMonths(1) <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            settings = // DB.GetSettings();
            LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return settings;
    }
```

This will keep settings in memory and load it again every month or when you reset IIS or update your project.

Of course If you need something bigger than that, you can use no-sql tool like (Redis or mongoDB) as a caching layer.

Hope that Help